# When I going to insert 1500 byte data at datastore , get an error

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'google\appengine\runtime\ApplicationError' with message 'The value of
>   property "result" is longer than 1500 bytes.' in
>   /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/RealApiProxy.php:53
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/ApiProxy.php(40):
>   google\appengine\runtime\RealApiProxy->makeSyncCall('datastore_v4',
>   'Commit', Object(google\appengine\datastore\v4\CommitRequest),
>   Object(google\appengine\datastore\v4\CommitResponse), 60) #1
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~apigraymatics/1.390460898442825180/public/data/GDS/Gateway/ProtoBuf.php(220):
>   google\appengine\runtime\ApiProxy::makeSyncCall('datastore_v4',
>   'Commit', Object(google\appengine\datastore\v4\CommitRequest),
>   Object(google\appengine\datastore\v4\CommitResponse), 60) #2
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~apigraymatics/1.390460898442825180/public/data/GDS/Gateway/ProtoBuf.php(101):
>   GDS\Gateway\ProtoBuf->execute('Commit',
>   Object(google\appengine\datastore\v4\CommitRequest),
>   Object(google\appengine\datastore\v4\Com in
>   /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/RealApiProxy.php
>   on line 53

My code is :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include_once 'GDS/Entity.php';  
include_once 'GDS/Gateway.php'; 
include_once 'GDS/Store.php';  
include_once 'GDS/Schema.php'; 
include_once 'GDS/Mapper.php';  
include_once 'GDS/Gateway/ProtoBuf.php';  
include_once 'GDS/Mapper/ProtoBuf.php'; 
$obj = new GDS\Entity(); 
$obj_gateway_ns1 = new GDS\Gateway\ProtoBuf(null, '<namespace>');
$obj_store = new GDS\Store('<kind>', $obj_gateway_ns1);
$obj_schema = new GDS\Schema('<kind>');
$obj_schema->addString('transaction_id',FALSE);
$obj_schema->addString('result',FALSE);
$obj_schema->addString('image',FALSE);
$insert_data = array('transaction_id'=>'sbc','result'=>'1500byte','media_type'=>'image');
$obj = $obj_store->createEntity($insert_data);
$res = $obj_store->upsert($obj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it after study GDS library

```
$obj = new GDS\Entity();
$obj_gateway_ns1 = new GDS\Gateway\ProtoBuf(null, 'name-space');
$obj_store = new GDS\Store('<kind-name>', $obj_gateway_ns1);
$obj_schema = new GDS\Schema('<kind-name>');
$obj_schema->addString('transaction_id');
$obj_schema->addString('result',FALSE);
$obj_schema->addString('image');
$obj_store = new GDS\Store($obj_schema, $obj_gateway_ns1);
$insert_data = array('transaction_id'=>'sbc','result'=>1500byte,'media_type'=>'image');
$obj = $obj_store->createEntity($insert_data);
$res = $obj_store->upsert($obj);
```

Thanks to Tom Walder for creating nice library

Comment: You are welcome. Indexed fields cannot be >1500 bytes. It's a Datastore restriction

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I solved it using

```
.set(BINARY_DATA, BlobValue.of(Blob.copyFrom(getBinaryData())).excludeFromIndexes());
```

instead of

```
.set(BINARY_DATA, Blob.copyFrom(getBinaryData()));
```